# How to convert multi line string to array of hashes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to convert basically a table stored in a string to an array of hashes. Here is my data:

```
model                 |part_number   |type             |serial_number   |
----------------------|--------------|-----------------|----------------|
SCBE-MX-S             |750-031391    |CB               |ZV1111          |
SCBE-MX-S             |750-031391    |CB               |ZR1111          |
SCBE-MX-S             |750-031391    |CB               |ZV1111          |
```

How can I put this into an array of hashes?

So basically it would look like

```
array 0
model => SCBE-MX-S
PartNumber => 750-031391
type => CB
serialNumber => ZV1111

array 1
......
```

Here is my code so far. It works decent but now I need to convert to using an array of hashes instead of just a single array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;
my @data_;
my @index_;

my $input = `lrm show -t=model,part_number,type,serial_number component\\(chassis_resource_name=wf-nashville\\)`;

@data=split(/\n/, $input);

foreach my $token (@data){
  @data_ = split(/\|/,$token);
  my %fields = (
    "model" => $data_[0],
    "partNumber" => $data_[1],
    "type" => $data_[2],
    "serialNumber" => $data_[3],
  );
  push @index_, \%fields;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@index_;
```

Output

```
 [
  {
    model => "25 records found.",
    partNumber => undef,
    serialNumber => undef,
    type => undef,
  },
  {
    model => "model                 ",
    partNumber => "part_number   ",
    serialNumber => "serial_number   ",
    type => "type             ",
  },
  {
    model => ("-" x 22),
    partNumber => "--------------",
    serialNumber => "----------------",
    type => "-----------------",
  },
```

Comment: Split into an array of strings on the line break; map with a function that turns a single line into a single hash.

Comment: I'm new to Perl, so I am stuck on what to actually code to make this happen.

Comment: [You are expected to put forth some effort.](http://whathaveyoutried.com) We are not your personal code monkeys.

Comment: What exactly would you guys like me to do? I have been trying different things all day which do not work. I can post them up if you want but since I am new to Perl I have no clue what I am doing, so all my code is incorrect. All I am asking for is help. Do you have a link where I can find sample code of something similar that I can start with? Can you give me a name of a built in function that I should look up that can do this? I am not asking for exact code, but I do need a starting place. Telling me your unwilling to help, is extremely unhelpful.

Comment: Okay, first question: why are you `split`ting on `/^/`?

Comment: To get each line in a separate array element.

Comment: I guess that technically works, since regexes without the `/s` modifier don't include new lines. It would be better practice, however, to split upon whatever EOL character you're using.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you attempt to create an array of hash references.

Comment: That is because I am still working on that. I was just able to get this working properly.

Comment: Well, it looks as though you have the tokens you need (although you probably want to filter out the tokens consisting of dashes). Loop through your tokens and map each part to the correct data type. Don't forget to store the mapping in a final array.

Comment: That is what I am at right now. It doesn't compile because it has errors which is why I hadn't posted it.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely not compile. First of all, you didn't declare `%fields` anywhere. Secondly, you should be assigning particular keys in `%fields` to particular values, not using [hash slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

Comment: This is what I have now.

Comment: That definitely looks better. By the way, for printing out somewhat complicated data structures, [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper) is your friend. Also, is there a reason why you're appending a `"\n"` to `$fields{serialNumber}`?

Comment: That was just so I could read it better. This is going to be pushed to another script, so once I am sure it is working correctly I will take that out.

Comment: Also, you don't want to push `%fields` onto `@index_`, but rather `\%fields`--ie a reference to `%fields`. The problem is that Perl automatically flattens all arrays and lists. Take a look at [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: Why is my output not nice and organized like the example below? Is it the second line in his while loop that is organizing it? Nevermind, your previous comment answered this.

Comment: @JackManey This is now working, I just need to pull all the useless data out, like the first few lines. Thanks for all your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I am very disappointed that you appear to have made no effort at all to solve this simple problem yourself, however this will do as you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;

while (<DATA>) {
  my %fields;
  @fields{qw/ model PartNumber type serialNumber /} = /[^\s|]+/g;
  push @data, \%fields if $fields{PartNumber} =~ /\d/;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;


__DATA__
model                 |part_number   |type             |serial_number   |
----------------------|--------------|-----------------|----------------|
SCBE-MX-S             |750-031391    |CB               |ZV1111          |
SCBE-MX-S             |750-031391    |CB               |ZR1111          |
SCBE-MX-S             |750-031391    |CB               |ZV1111          |
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    model => "SCBE-MX-S",
    PartNumber => "750-031391",
    serialNumber => "ZV1111",
    type => "CB",
  },
  {
    model => "SCBE-MX-S",
    PartNumber => "750-031391",
    serialNumber => "ZR1111",
    type => "CB",
  },
  {
    model => "SCBE-MX-S",
    PartNumber => "750-031391",
    serialNumber => "ZV1111",
    type => "CB",
  },
]
```

Comment: Maybe it is simple to someone experienced in Perl, which is possibly why I am having trouble finding this online but I am new and this is difficult for me. What exactly is <DATA>? This is seems to not work for a string variable in place of <DATA>.

Comment: @Korey - [Search engines exist.](http://perldoc.perl.org/SelfLoader.html) [Use them.](http://startperl.blogspot.com/2007/12/data-virtual-file-in-perl.html)

Comment: If you have so little knowledge of Perl that you don't stand a chance of writing it yourself then you should either go away and learn the language or hire a programmer to code it for you. It is not an excuse to ask for free programming effort on Stack Overflow. `DATA` is a built-in file handle that allows you to read data from the same file as the program source after the `__DATA__` marker as a convenience. You would need to either `open` the real file, or pass the name of the file as a command-line parameter and use `<>` to read from it.

Comment: The problem with search engines is you need to know what it is your looking for information on. I didn't know what to search, but thank you. So his code makes sense to me for a file now, but I am confused on how I iterate through a string line by line, like you can with a file.

Comment: @Korey - You're not thinking about what you're reading. `<DATA>` is a filehandle. You can read from it line by line just as you would a file (after you `open` it, of course).

Comment: @Korey - I'd heavily recommend picking up a copy of [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) and reading through it.

Comment: I understand that now. I cannot use a file. What I am doing is pulling data from a cli program earlier in my code. I can only save this information as a string. Is my only solution to save this string to a file, then reopen that file to parse it? That seems counterproductive to me, so I have to guess there is a way to do what this code is doing, but with a string instead of a filehandle.

Comment: I actually have that book in front of me. I've read through most of it, and while it is helpful, I need a more in depth book.

Comment: @Korey - If the string is exactly as you'd find it in the file--with EOL characters--then you can split on `\n` (or `\r\n` or `\r` depending on which EOL style you're using), and voila! You have your lines.

Comment: @Korey - If you have that book in front of you, then a simple index search would reveal that the `DATA` filehandle is discussed on page 91 (of the 6th edition, anyway). And although that doesn't go into detail about `__DATA__`, it leads you to a simple search of `perl data filehandle`.

Comment: @JackManey Yes you are right, I didn't think of that because I assumed it was just the name he had given the filehandle, it didn't cross my mind that it was common enough to be in the index. Do you have a suggestion of books that go into more detail I should get after I am done with this book?

Comment: @Korey: It sounds to me like you are a *long* way off needing something more advanced to read.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for your input, but I learn best by doing, and I can't do that with this book.

Comment: @Korey: But you *aren't* "doing", you are asking us to "do" for you. [Programming Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) is the authority on all of Perl, or there is [Intermediate Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012689.do) and [Mastering Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012702.do). On the internet there is [Learn Perl](http://learn.perl.org/), which has a list of tutorials. And PerlMonks has [this list of tutorials](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Tutorials). But I don't know why I'm telling you this: I'm sure you can search the internet as well as I.

Comment: I never asked anyone to code my script for me. I am trying to ask for help. I don't know all the Perl lingo so it is difficult to search for exactly what I need help with. That is the reason I posted here. Is there anyway to post my code besides in a comment? I will post what I have so far.

Comment: @Korey - Edit your question.

Comment: @JackManey I was hoping there was a better way, but thanks.

Comment: @Korey - Aaaand...what, exactly, were you hoping for?